# Is it dangerous to establish WebSocket connection in a js file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

So, basically, I have this code :

```
let socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/server.php');

socket.onopen = () => {
    console.log('connection established !');
}
```

I use this code to establish a connection for a Real-Time Quiz. But after going to the Sources page of my inspector, I can see the whole javascript code in my browser, including `ws://localhost:8080/server.php`. Is it dangerous to show it (unintentionally) ? If someones creates a script and puts in it the same url (not localhost, it's just an example), can he receive/send data to the server ?

Comment: Probably as much as they can send arbitrary data over plain HTTP. If there is no authentication in place, anybody can send requests and receive data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes,it is dangerous. u can:

1. verify the client http request header for example 'Origin'. make sure the client website is the right client website.
2. use a TSL websocket service, visit to the server over SSL. So the protocol is changing to: wss://
3. give the client a request token, put this token in header or in post data, the server verify this token.
4. check the request times of a client in limited time. make sure a specific client won't request too frequently

Comment: Alright thank you! I think i'll combine the SSL and the token.